# Android WebView turned black when filling out a form

Tags: android, forms, webview

I encounter this problem when filling out a form loaded by my app using android webview:

https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-lik5GC5CcIU/T0W5n9dJeTI/AAAAAAAABrM/JIlqB5_Tq9Q/s1130/webview-blackout-problem.jpg

Sorry, I can't directly post the image because I'm new here so StackOverflow won't allow me.

As you can see, some part of the screen turned black when I tried to fill out a text field. Thanks for any help!

Code I use:

```
package com.example.WebViewer;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Window;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class WebViewerActivity extends Activity {
     /** Called when the activity is first created. */
     @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          //setContentView(R.layout.main);

          // Let's display the progress in the activity title bar, like the
          // browser app does.
          getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);

          WebView webview = new WebView(this);
          setContentView(webview);

          webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

          final Activity activity = this;
          webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
          public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
               // Activities and WebViews measure progress with different scales.
               // The progress meter will automatically disappear when we reach 100%
               activity.setProgress(progress * 1000);
          }
        });

        webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {      
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
                      //Users will be notified in case there's an error (i.e. no internet connection)
                      Toast.makeText(activity, "Oh no! " + description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        //This will load the webpage that we want to see

        String url = "file:///" 
                        + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() 
                        + "/SomeFiles/Downloads/SalesOrderForms/4_2.html";

        webview.loadUrl(url);

        Log.e("URL", url);

     }
}
```

I also use jQuery on that page. I tried to removed it but I got the same results.

I tried viewing it in HTML viewer but instead of black, some parts of the screen turned white.

I tried viewing it in the device browser and it seemed ok.

I'm using 10.1 inch samsung galaxy tab. with android 3.0 os

Comment: @Paresh Mayani, thanks for editing :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried :

```
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); // TRUE because you are using JS as you said
```

Comment: Thanks or your reply @ChristopheCVB, yes, i tried it 'true' first then i made it 'false' but i got the same result...